# What is the use of Browse tab in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, custom-masterpage

I have seen the "BROWSE" tab in SharePoint 2013 pages and lists etc..
some pages are not showing browse tab.I am not sure , what is the use of this.

Suggest an information about Browse tab.

Comment: Is it for specific browser? In which browser it is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Browse tab is particularly useful when you have top navigation enabled. Browse tab hides the ribbon and shows the top navigation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes , I think browse tab is used only to hide the toggle in SharePoint ribbon.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of this tab is hiding of the most Ribbon interface in page read mode - when the Ribbon isn't needed.

When the Browse tab is displayed the Ribbon gets minimized for saving of useful page space. The height of the Ribbon is reducing to the height of tabs headers area.

BROWSE hides the ribbon (if you were in PAGE/FILE/LIBRARY tab) and shows your top navigation menu (which you can add or remove links to it)
[Check this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/fd71373a-1747-4232-890b-1aa6732db3ec/browse-tab-in-ribbon-does-not-do-anything?forum=sharepointgeneral) and [this](http://blog.alexboev.com/2012/01/browse-tab-in-sharepoint-2010-ribbon.html)